# Cannot open SDK Manager in Eclipse ide

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I understand and appreciate that this question may have been asked many times before, but I've tried many of the solutions in the other questions asked, but nothing has worked.

I read that it was a path issue with java, but both my class and path environment variables have the right path to the java files in the lib folders.

When I click on SDK manager in the eclipse IDE, I receive a message with a loading bar saying that it will open up soon, however nothing opens at all.

I've also tried to open up the SDK manager.exe manually, even as an administrator but this still hasn't solved the issue.

I'm really losing my marbles over this, please someone help me :(

Just to confirm, these are what i have in my environment variables for:

`Path: C:\Users\Shan\Documents\Computer Science - YEAR 2\Android App Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-2013`

`Class: .C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\lib`

and `comspec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`

My OS is windows 7

EDIT: There seems to be two SDK Manager exe files. One is inside of the tools/lib folder; I have clicked it and i was given the following error message:

'`Failed to execute tools\android.bat: the system cannot find the file specified`'

Comment: trying reinstalling the sdk, if you have'nt

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've already tried that :(

Comment: What happens when you open the exe directly? does it just not open at all?

Comment: The cmd screen flashes for a split second. It opens and closes right away

Comment: Open a command window. Run the `android` command directly in it. That way, you will be able to see whatever error message is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your response Commons. It says the command is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You need to be in the `tools` directory of your SDK installation, or add that directory to your `PATH`, for `android` to work from the command line.

Comment: The error message that I get is 'Failed to execute tools\android.bat: the system cannot find the file specified'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a similar problem today. Press the Windows button and Search for android.bat(in the search programs and files text field)

Then copy the file to your android sdk folder (`C:\Users\Shan\Documents\Computer Science - YEAR 2\Android App Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\tools\`).

After that dont run SDK manager but run the android.bat file.

Hope this helps

-Zaniar